# How can I save content inside the textbox binding to combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, telerik

I'm just wondering If I could save/ store the text inside the textbox and displays all the text whenever I open back my application?
The situation is that I made a calendar with two combo boxes; one is for years and the second one is for months. When I select one of the items from one of my two combo boxes the days changes with the corresponding text boxes in which I could type in.

I consider saving it with the use of isolated storage of Telerik but it only saves the current selected dates and years but it doesn't save the text I input from those text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Using SaveFileDialog you can save the textbox text to a text file easily.
Please check below MSDN examples.

**During OnPropertyChanged :**

```
// Create a file to write to. 
string createText = textBox.Text + Environment.NewLine;
File.WriteAllText("D:\\TextFile.txt", createText);

// Open the file to read from. 
string readText = File.ReadAllText("D:\\TextFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried the code but it doesn't store the text ... textboxes are still empty whenever I open back the app.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do it in .NET is the app.config mechanism:

1. Create the data in app.config
2. Initialize your textbox on loading (e.g in Form constructor):

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
     InitializeComponent();

     textBoxBasePath.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.BasePath;
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Save the data on  closing:

   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       Properties.Settings.Default.BasePath = textBoxBasePath.Text;
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   }

For further details, read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you fro your respond.. I just figured out that my textbox has its own property of addressing  all the input texts.. Here is the snippet of my textbox code: `<TextBox  telerik:PersistenceManager.StorageId="myText"    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Text="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" />` it is coded inside the **ResourceDictionary**, the Notes is the source path of the property...